# How to create a sticky navbar on react (inside a div)

Tags: css, reactjs

As far as i know when creating a sticky navbar, `position: sticky; top: 0;` can't have a parent / inside another div.

but in jsx, all of the components must be inside a div / have a parent.

```
function App() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
          <Navbar />
          <Content />
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default App;
```

this is the css

```
.navbar {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

do i have to use some javascript for this? i'll be happy if someone can solve this with only css.

**EDIT**

it fixed itself after i forgetting about it. i swear i didn't change anything, what the hell

Comment: "but in jsx, all of the components must be inside a div / have a parent." > Not at all :) `return <Navbar />`

Comment: but then i can't put other components tho. "JSX expressions must have one parent element.ts(2657)"

Comment: You have `<Fragment>` or just `<>...</>` for that :)

Answer (score 0):

**Navbar** or **Navbar.js** either you can create external file or do this in your **App.js**

```
function Navbar(props) {
  return <nav ...props></nav>;
};

export default Navbar;
```

as you have passed `...props` inside the `Navbar` function it will allow you do add `className`, `style` and many more attributes and properties inside the `<Navbar />` tag.

After that in your **App.js**

```
import Navbar from 'navbar-path';

function App() {
  return (
    <Navbar className="navbar" />
  );
};
```

And then you can do *styling like you wanted*

```css
.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blueviolet
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

**The second method you can do is you can use `styled-components`**. If you are creating this in external file don't forget to export it.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Navbar = styled.nav`
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blueviolet
  justify-content: space-around;
`
/* after doing this you don't need to pass ...props or anything */

function App() {
  return <Navbar />
}
```

**The third method you can do is style your navbar initially before calling it inside `App` function**

**Navbar.js**

```
function Navbar() {
  return <nav className="navbar"></nav>
}
```

then `navbar.css` or your one css file i.e is `main.css` or anything

```css
.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blueviolet
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

**[UPDATE]** if you don't want any parent element or you don't want wrap your inside a div.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Content />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: i edited my post, i now have other components inside App.js. And if i put the `<Navbar />` outside of div.app, it shows error  "JSX expressions must have one parent element.ts(2657)"

Comment: that's because components can only have one `parent`. See I have updated my answer.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me! but it seems like the problem is gone itself, and i swear i didn't change anything